# Converting Bash script to PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell

I am writing a Wifi test script in Powershell. I have managed to do it in Bash and now I want to port it. I am looking for command similar to:

1. Syslog: to log WPA and SSID changes.
2. Iwconfig: which logs current wifi config

Here's my current script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/var/log/syslog | grep SSID /var/log/syslog | grep wpa
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you say what data you are looking for.

Comment: Found the iwconfig, netsh wlan interface show

But I want to log if it changes Access point

Comment: Please post your current bash script and it's results.

Comment: /var/log/syslog | grep SSID

/var/log/syslog | grep wpa

http://pastebin.com/N1jSd0J2

Answer (score 0):

Windows dont work like linux do and so on..
So there is much to think of here and there are no simple way to get the information that you want here.

---

**"1. Syslog: to log WPA and SSID changes"**

For this one we would need to bind the drivers you have and make them output it to where it should be readable.
And so on..

**"2. Iwconfig: which logs current wifi config"**

This..
ipconfig is the command who is closest but dosent do what you want in this one.

---

I would suggest that you try something in visual basic or maybe python.
Dont think it is a simple way to do this..

*Hope it helped somehow.*